# Locking plane for a long period

Tags: transforms

When I am modeling and know I will only be transforming across X/Y for a while, I would like to lock Z for an extended period instead of having to press Shift+Z every time I transform. Is there anyway to lock a plane for a long period?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just lock the transformations in the *properties panel* (<kbd>N</kbd>)- click the *padlock icon* of the axis you want to lock.
[image]